# Using freeze in JIProlog

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, freeze, cycle, edge-list

I want to do a graph search with JIProlog. The below example works fine without the `memberchk`, but then it returns paths with cycles, which I don't want. When I do include it, however, Prolog freezes, probably because of the infinite search.

```
connected(ac,a,b). connected(ac,a,c). connected(ac,b,c). 
connected(ac,b,a). connected(ac,c,a). connected(ac,c,b).

path(A,B,[AB]) :- connected(AB,A,B).
path(A,C,[H|T]) :- connected(H,A,B), path(B,C,T), \+ memberchk(H,T).
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607611/simple-graph-search-in-prolog/1608551#1608551) I found why (the list of edges is not yet instantiated) and a hint to a solution (using `freeze/2`). However, `freeze/2` doesn't work in JIProlog, which is what I'm using. Can anyone help me to an alternative solution?

**Edit:** I know for graphs in general it would be a solution to keep track of nodes instead, such as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797793/how-to-visit-each-point-in-directed-graph/10800569#10800569) example, but for my particular application the "nodes" can also be *on* an edge, which is why I want to check for edges that were visited rather than nodes that were visited.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10800569/874024) answer

Comment: Thanks. However, I was looking for a solution where it is being checked whether tracks have been visited, rather than nodes. I edited the question to state this explicitly.

Comment: If you really need it, you could experiment with a meta-interpreter as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35133159/502187

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your requirement. I would try to adapt the suggested answer.

```
% get a path from start to end
path(Start, End, Path) :-
    path(Start, End, [], Path).

path(A, B, Visited, [AB|Visited]) :- connected(AB, A, B).

path(A, C, Visited, Path) :-
    connected(AB, A, B),
    \+ memberchk(AB, Visited),
    path(B, C, [AB|Visited], Path).
```

beware: untested code....