# How to write/edit own coroutines in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, freeze, coroutine, prolog-coroutining

I would like to build my own coroutines in Prolog.
I'd like to add some extra functionalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use the term-expansion mechanism provided by some Prolog systems and Logtalk to rewrite calls to e.g. the `freeze/2` predicate to do the extra steps you want. One must be careful, however, to not expand a call to a predicate into another goal that calls the same predicate as goal-expansion is recursively applied until a fixed-point is reached. The Logtalk implementation of the term-expansion mechanism makes it easy to avoid this trap (with the additional advantage of portability as you can use Logtalk with most Prolog systems) by using a compiler bypass control construct, `{}/1`. A silly example would be:

```
:- object(my_expansions,
    implements(expanding)).

    goal_expansion(
        freeze(Var,Goal),
        (   write('If you instantiate me, I will run away!\n'),
            {freeze(Var,Goal)},  % goal will not be further expanded
            write('Bye!\n')
        )
    ).

:- end_object.
```

This object can then be used as an hook object for the compilation of source files containing calls to `freeze/2` that you want to expand. Something like (assuming that the object above is saved in a file with the name `my_expansions.lgt` and that the source file that you want to expand is named `source.lgt`):

```
?- logtalk_load(my_expansions), logtalk_load(source, [hook(my_expansions)]).
```

For full details see the Logtalk documentation and examples.

There might be a **clean** way that I'm not aware of doing the same using the a Prolog system own term-expansion mechanism implementation. Anyone?

Comment: Okay. Can you explain how freeze actually works. I'm really looking to simulate the actions undertaken by Prolog.

Comment: Look into your Prolog system documentation section on attributed variables.

Comment: Can I use goal_expansion also to widen the functionality of =/2 ?

Comment: Short answer, yes. As long as the Prolog system you're using provides a term-expansion mechanism, you should be able to define clauses for `goal_expansion/2` that will expand calls to e.g. `=/2` found on a source file being compiled.

Comment: Can it be that the code you posted does not work? At least I run out of stack.

Comment: I tried to simplify the solution that I use for these kind of tasks to fit what's common between Prolog systems implementation of the term-expansion mechanism (that is far from standard) but introduced an error. Fixed now in my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

Writing a vanilla interpreter for coroutines should be on the teaching list of every Prolog course. It is quite simple, here you see the normal vanilla interpreter, simplified:

```
% solve(+Term)
solve(true).
solve((A,B)) :- solve(A), solve(B).
solve(H) :- clause(H, B), solve(B).
```

Now for corouting, in the sense of suspending goals via freeze/2, just add an additional input output parameter pair with the delayed goals, for a specification of select/3 see (*):

```
% solve(+Term, +List, -List)
solve(G, L, R) :- select(freeze(V, F), L, H), 
   nonvar(V), !, 
   solve((F,G), H, R).
solve(freeze(V, G), L, [freeze(V,G)|L]) :- var(V), !.
solve(freeze(_, G), L, R) :- solve(G, L, R).
solve(true, L, L).
solve((A,B), L, R) :- solve(A, L, H), solve(B, H, R).
solve(H, L, R) :- clause(H, B), solve(B, L, R).
```

You can use the above vanilla interpreter to study different wake-up strategies. I am not sure whether it captures existing Prolog systems. But you could run examples such as:

```
?- freeze(X, member(X, [the(1), the(2)])), X = the(Y).
```

successfully, by posing the following question:

```
?- solve((freeze(X, member(X, [the(1), the(2)])), X = the(Y), true), [], L).
```

The ", true" is needed to check a last time for woken up goals. If L is returned empty then all frozen goals where woken up. Otherwise there are some pending frozen goals. Which is sometimes called floundering.

The above prototype also leads to a natural implementation of coroutines via thin attributes, the undo/1 and some little support of the interpreter by a goal injection queue. I will post about this soon somewhere else.

Bye

(*)
https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue

Comment: An other meta-interpreters is for example found here, for example on page 167: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.460.2981&rep=rep1&type=pdf